# How to compare two tables using PL/SQL function?

Tags: function, plsql

I am new to plsql and struggling to write the code.. I want to compare two tables using plsql functions, (two tables are exactly same except the records). Input arguments will be (table1, table2) - it should compare table1 and table2 and return three outputs.

1. Any mismatched record between tables
2. Any row which exist in table1 and doesn't exist in table2.
3. Any  row which exist in table2 and doesn't exist in table1.

I wrote the query in SQL and it worked but I have hard-coded a particular table name here.
Please advise how to convert into a function.

```
SET TERMOUT OFF CONCAT OFF VERIFY OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET MARKUP HTML ON SPOOL ON
SPOOL ACTION.HTML
set pages 1000 lines 125

----
PROMPT SHOWING THE DIFFERENCE WITH THE MATCHING RECORDS FOR TABLE ACTION
BREAK ON ACTIONID  duplicates skip page
column tblname format a10
select ACTIONID,tblname "tblname",ACTIONDESC,ACTIONNAME
from ((SELECT 'OLD VALUES' tblname,ACTIONID,ACTIONDESC,ACTIONNAME
FROM 'DEPL_ACTION
MINUS
SELECT 'NEW VALUES'  tblname,ACTIONID,ACTIONDESC,ACTIONNAME
FROM ACTION )
UNION ALL
( SELECT 'NEW VALUES'  tblname,ACTIONID,ACTIONDESC,ACTIONNAME
FROM ACTION
MINUS
SELECT 'OLD VALUES' tblname,ACTIONID,ACTIONDESC,ACTIONNAME
FROM 'DEPL_ACTION )) aa  where (ACTIONID) in ( select ACTIONID from (
(SELECT ACTIONID,ACTIONDESC,ACTIONNAME
FROM 'DEPL_ACTION
MINUS
SELECT ACTIONID,ACTIONDESC,ACTIONNAME
FROM ACTION )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ACTIONID,ACTIONDESC,ACTIONNAME
FROM ACTION
MINUS
SELECT ACTIONID,ACTIONDESC,ACTIONNAME
FROM 'DEPL_ACTION ) )  group by ACTIONID having count(*) > 1 ) order by ACTIONID;
CLEAR BREAKS

PROMPT SHOWING THE EXTRA RECORDS IN OLD VALUES FOR TABLE ACTION
select ACTIONID,tblname "tblname",ACTIONDESC,ACTIONNAME
from ((SELECT 'OLD VALUES' tblname,ACTIONID,ACTIONDESC,ACTIONNAME
FROM 'DEPL_ACTION
MINUS
SELECT 'NEW VALUES'  tblname,ACTIONID,ACTIONDESC,ACTIONNAME
FROM ACTION )
UNION ALL
( SELECT 'NEW VALUES'  tblname,ACTIONID,ACTIONDESC,ACTIONNAME
FROM ACTION
MINUS
SELECT 'OLD VALUES' tblname,ACTIONID,ACTIONDESC,ACTIONNAME
FROM 'DEPL_ACTION )) aa  where (ACTIONID) in ( select ACTIONID from (
(SELECT ACTIONID,ACTIONDESC,ACTIONNAME
FROM 'DEPL_ACTION
MINUS
SELECT ACTIONID,ACTIONDESC,ACTIONNAME
FROM ACTION )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ACTIONID,ACTIONDESC,ACTIONNAME
FROM ACTION
MINUS
SELECT ACTIONID,ACTIONDESC,ACTIONNAME
FROM 'DEPL_ACTION ) )  group by ACTIONID having count(*) = 1 )  order by ACTIONID;

PROMPT SHOWING THE EXTRA RECORDS IN NEW VALUES FOR TABLE ACTION
select ACTIONID,tblname "tblname",ACTIONDESC,ACTIONNAME
from ((SELECT 'OLD VALUES' tblname,ACTIONID,ACTIONDESC,ACTIONNAME
FROM 'DEPL_ACTION
MINUS
SELECT 'NEW VALUES'  tblname,ACTIONID,ACTIONDESC,ACTIONNAME
FROM ACTION )
UNION ALL
( SELECT 'NEW VALUES'  tblname,ACTIONID,ACTIONDESC,ACTIONNAME
FROM ACTION
MINUS
SELECT 'OLD VALUES' tblname,ACTIONID,ACTIONDESC,ACTIONNAME
FROM 'DEPL_ACTION )) aa  where (ACTIONID) in ( select ACTIONID from (
(SELECT ACTIONID,ACTIONDESC,ACTIONNAME
FROM 'DEPL_ACTION
MINUS
SELECT ACTIONID,ACTIONDESC,ACTIONNAME
FROM ACTION )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ACTIONID,ACTIONDESC,ACTIONNAME
FROM ACTION
MINUS
SELECT ACTIONID,ACTIONDESC,ACTIONNAME
FROM 'DEPL_ACTION ) )  group by ACTIONID having count(*) = 1 ) order by ACTIONID;



SET MARKUP HTML OFF
SPOOL OFF
EXIT
```

Comment: Which part are you struggling with? Accepting a table name in a function, or projecting rows from a function, or something else?

Comment: which return type i should be using if i want to do the above??@DavidAldridge

Comment: Firstly I'd question why you're doing this with a function at all -- the result derives directly from SQL, so you might embed the logic in a view for convenience, but using a function does not seem to be a good choice

Comment: i have to embed this in a suite . So i cannot use sqlplus . so we will be getting DB connection in an encrypted manner , so we thought to use a function @DavidAldridge

Comment: Can this environment not just run a query against the database?

Comment: it can run queries , but i have to avoid sqlplus logins, i have a fileexecutor jar for that, the below approach is working but i have to make it generic ,, working on it thnks @DavidAldridge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not create a one ultimate function for it, it will be extremely hard to maintain it. Create one package per tables couple.

Header:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE tab_a_pkg AS

    TYPE tab_a_ntt IS TABLE OF tab_a%ROWTYPE;

    FUNCTION mismatched RETURN tab_a_ntt;

    FUNCTION a_minus_b RETURN tab_a_ntt;

    FUNCTION b_minus_a RETURN tab_a_ntt;

END tab_a_pkg;
```

Body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY tab_a_pkg AS

    FUNCTION mismatched RETURN tab_a_ntt
    AS
        l_return  tab_a_ntt;
    BEGIN
        SELECT  NVL(col_a1, col_b1) AS col_1
        ,       NVL(col_a2, col_b2) AS col_2
        BULK    COLLECT INTO l_return
        FROM    tab_a
        FULL    JOIN tab_b
        ON      col_a1 = col_b1
        AND     col_a2 = col_b2
        WHERE   col_a1 IS NULL
        OR      col_b1 IS NULL;

        RETURN l_return;
    END mismatched;



    FUNCTION a_minus_b RETURN tab_a_ntt
    AS
        l_return  tab_a_ntt;
    BEGIN
        SELECT  *
        BULK    COLLECT INTO l_return
        FROM
        (
            SELECT * FROM tab_a
            MINUS
            SELECT * FROM tab_b
        );

        RETURN l_return;
    END a_minus_b;



    FUNCTION b_minus_a RETURN tab_a_ntt
    AS
        l_return  tab_a_ntt;
    BEGIN
        SELECT  *
        BULK    COLLECT INTO l_return
        FROM
        (
            SELECT * FROM tab_b
            MINUS
            SELECT * FROM tab_a
        );

        RETURN l_return;
    END b_minus_a;

END tab_a_pkg;
```

Run:

```
DECLARE
    l_tab_a  tab_a_pkg.tab_a_ntt;
BEGIN
    l_tab_a := tab_a_pkg.mismatched();

    FOR indx IN 1..l_tab_a.COUNT LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_tab_a(indx).col_a1 || ' ' || l_tab_a(indx).col_a2);
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('------');


    l_tab_a := tab_a_pkg.a_minus_b();

    FOR indx IN 1..l_tab_a.COUNT LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_tab_a(indx).col_a1 || ' ' || l_tab_a(indx).col_a2);
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('------');


    l_tab_a := tab_a_pkg.b_minus_a();

    FOR indx IN 1..l_tab_a.COUNT LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_tab_a(indx).col_a1 || ' ' || l_tab_a(indx).col_a2);
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('------');
END;
/*
23 223
24 224
13 123
14 124
------
13 123
14 124
------
23 223
24 224
------
*/
```

Comment: The above code works fine , should we create packages for each pair of tables, i have to compare 12 pairs of table, does that means 12 different packages?? @the_slk

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you have to do a change for 1 of the couples, other 11 are safe. It is easy to maintain, test and release.

Answer (score 0):

this proc store is perhaps as you search
I posted it into another topics in this site but I don't remember which one:)

use to compare selected fields in 2 tables with same pk
ps_TableGap 'tbl1','tbl2', 'fld1,fld2,fld3...fields of tbl1', 'Fld4,fld5,fld6...fields of tbl2 (optional us as tbl1 is empty)'

you have 3 results base on tbl1 'DEL', 'ADD', 'GAP' 
fields of tbl2 are prefixed with _ to be differents (need to have diifferent fields name to push result inreporting service)

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ps_TableGap]    Script Date: 10/03/2013 16:03:44 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:       Arnaud ALLAVENA
-- Create date: 03.10.2013
-- Description: Compare tables
-- =============================================
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[ps_TableGap]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Tbl1 as varchar(100),@Tbl2 as varchar(100),@Fld1 as varchar(1000), @Fld2 as varchar(1000)= ''
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
--Variables
--@Tbl1 = table 1
--@Tbl2 = table 2
--@Fld1 = Fields to compare from table 1
--@Fld2 Fields to compare from table 2
Declare @SQL varchar(8000)= '' --SQL statements
Declare @nLoop int = 1 --loop counter
Declare @Pk varchar(1000)= '' --primary key(s) 
Declare @Pk1 varchar(1000)= '' --first field of primary key
declare @strTmp varchar(50) = '' --returns value in Pk determination
declare @FldTmp varchar (1000) = '' --temporarily fields for alias calculation

--If @Fld2 empty we take @Fld1
--fields rules: fields to be compare must be in same order and type - always returns Gap
If @Fld2 = '' Set @Fld2 = @Fld1

--Change @Fld2 with Alias prefix xxx become _xxx 
while charindex(',',@Fld2)>0
begin
    Set @FldTmp = @FldTmp + (select substring(@Fld2,1,charindex(',',@Fld2)-1) + ' as _' + substring(@Fld2,1,charindex(',',@Fld2)-1) + ',')
    Set @Fld2 = (select ltrim(right(@Fld2,len(@Fld2)-charindex(',',@Fld2))))
end
Set @FldTmp = @FldTmp + @Fld2 + ' as _' + @Fld2
Set @Fld2 = @FldTmp

--Determinate primary key jointure
--rule: same pk in both tables
Set @nLoop = 1
Set @SQL = 'Declare crsr cursor for select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE where TABLE_NAME = '''
 + @Tbl1 + ''' or TABLE_SCHEMA + ''.'' + TABLE_NAME = ''' + @Tbl1 +  ''' or TABLE_CATALOG + ''.'' + TABLE_SCHEMA + ''.'' + TABLE_NAME = ''' + @Tbl1 
 + ''' order by ORDINAL_POSITION'
exec(@SQL)
open crsr 
fetch next from crsr into @strTmp
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin 
    if @nLoop = 1 
    begin 
        Set @Pk = 's.' + @strTmp + ' = b._' + @strTmp
        Set @Pk1 = @strTmp
        set @nLoop = @nLoop + 1 
    end 
    Else
    Set @Pk = @Pk + ' and s.' + @strTmp + ' = b._' + @strTmp
fetch next from crsr into @strTmp 

end 
close crsr
deallocate crsr

--SQL statement build
set @SQL = 'select case when s.' + @Pk1 + ' is null then ''Del'' when b._' + @Pk1 + ' is null then ''Add'' else ''Gap'' end as TypErr, '''
set @SQL = @SQL + @Tbl1 +''' as Tbl1, s.*, ''' + @Tbl2 +''' as Tbl2 ,b.* from (Select ' + @Fld1 + ' from ' + @Tbl1
set @SQL = @SQL + ' EXCEPT SELECT ' + @Fld2 + ' from ' + @Tbl2 + ')s full join (Select ' + @Fld2 + ' from ' + @Tbl2 
set @SQL = @SQL + ' EXCEPT SELECT ' + @Fld1 + ' from ' + @Tbl1 +')b on '+ @Pk 

--Run SQL statement
Exec(@SQL)
END
```